# How to add the unallocated space to root partition?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, gparted

[image: This is my GParted view]

This is my GParted view.
There is a 100GB of unallocated space at the very top. I want to add that space to `/dev/nvme0n1p1` or the `/` which is shown locked. I already searched online but most of the solutions had `linux-swap` partition involved somehow. I seem to have a `swap` file instead. Also it seems the order of these partitions as shown in GParted matters. Now, I want to safely add that extra space, i.e. without any data loss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Another alternative is to move /home to the new partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is quite straightforward. You will need:

1. A backup of any data you cannot afford to loose.
2. The means to boot into a live environment. The Ubuntu install media is perfect.

The steps are as follows

1. Boot into Windows and use the disk management tool to move the approximately 76GB VOLUME to the start of the disk. This will move the unallocated space next to your approximately 49GB Ubuntu root partition
2. Boot into the live environment (Try Ubuntu not install Ubuntu if you are using the Ubuntu install media)
3. Using GParted resize the approximately 49GB partition making use of the 100GB of unallocated space.

That’s it reboot into your enlarged Ubuntu install.

Good luck!

Comment: You should move the Ubuntu partition left (into the newly freed space), then expand it right, to avoid losing the filesystem at some random offset into the partition.

Comment: Thank you I was successful

Comment: @GX_V if my answer was successful for you please accept it. It will help others find answers that worked.

Comment: So basically, I booted from a live USB and opened GParted. At first, I moved `/dev/nvme0n1p3` to the left of the 100GB unallocated space.  Then I moved `/dev/nvme0n1p1` to the left of 100GB as well. So `/dev/nvme0n1p1` was sandwiched between the two. Then I extended it to the right covering the entire 100GB space. Hence, `/dev/nvme0n1p1` totalled approx 150GB.